# Abbreviation problem

Tags: acronyms

I have a problem with my report. I tried to change my list of abbreviation and the rest of my text is altered as well, i.e. not justified. Can someone help me figuring out what i have done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}%article type
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}%page size definition
\usepackage{ucs} %important for mac/windows compatibility
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %important for mac/windows compatibility (impose using UTF-8 character set)
\
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fullpage}%to use smaller margins
\usepackage{mathpazo}%changes the standard font to a "nicer" one

%various packages for math symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=MidnightBlue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black,pagebackref]{hyperref}

%to generate nicetables and graphics
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for nice tables
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\def\tabular{\small\oldtabular}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%to includes external PDF in latex document
\usepackage{eurosym}%to use the euro symbol
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{acro}


% list of abbreviation
\usepackage{acro}
% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{aed}{
  short = AED ,
  long  = Animal Estimated Dose ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{apoe}{
  short = ApoE ,
  long  = Apolipoprotein E ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{cldn}{
  short = Cldn ,
  long  = Claudin ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{ctnnb}{
  short = Ctnnb ,
  long  = Catenin beta,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{cvd}{
  short =  CVD,
  long  =  Cardio Vascular Disease,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{depc}{
  short = DEPC ,
  long  = Diethylpyrocarbonate ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{efsa}{
  short = EFSA ,
  long  = European Food Safety Autority ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{fmo}{
  short = FMO ,
  long  = Flavin mono-oxygenases ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{gadph}{
  short =  GADPH ,
  long  = Glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{hed}{
  short = HED,
  long  = Human estimated Dose ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{hmw}{
  short = HMW ,
  long  = High Molecular Weight ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{lmw}{
  short = LMW ,
  long  = Low Molecular Weight ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{lps}{
  short = LPS ,
  long  = Lipopolysaccharides ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{mw}{
  short = MW ,
  long  = Molecular Weight ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{nsp}{
  short = NSP ,
  long  = Non Starch Polysaccharide ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{rt}{
  short = RT,
  long  = Room Temperature ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{TLR-4}{
  short = TLR-4 ,
  long  = Toll like receptor 4 ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{tma}{
  short = TMA ,
  long  = Trimethylamine ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{tmao}{
  short = TMAO ,
  long  = Trimethylamine N-oxides ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{who}{
  short = WHO ,
  long  = World Health Organisation ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{zo1}{
  short = ZO-1 ,
  long  = Zonula Occludens 1 ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{zo2}{
  short = ZO-2 ,
  long  = Zonula Occludens 2 ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{idls}{
  short = IDLs ,
  long  = Intermediate-density lipoproteins ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{scfa}{
  short = SCFA ,
  long  = Short Chain Fatty Acids ,
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{ldl}{
  short = LDL,
  long  = Low Density Lipoprotein ,
  class = abbrev
}


\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

 \includegraphics[width= 60mm]{Agrosup.png} \hfill
 \includegraphics[width = 80mm]{hku-logo.png}\\[2cm]


\center % Center everything on the page
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE Stage de Recherche}\\[1.0cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large Formation ingénieur Agrosup Dijon }\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Formation initiale, sp\'ecialit\'e Agroalimentaire }\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge {Oat \textgreek{b} -glucan\,in\,ApoE-/- mice:\\ focus\,on\,the\,gut\,integrity\,and\,endotoxemia}}\\[0.4cm]
{\scriptsize \bf{Mots clés}:  \,\textit{Son d'avoine\, – \,Recherche\,– \,Experimentations\,– \, Bibliographie\,–\, Analyse critique. }% Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\textsc{\large Anais Zouaki}\\[1.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Enseignant r\'ef\'erent:}\\
Dr. Cosette \textsc{Grand-Valet} % Your name
{\small Agrosup Dijon}\\
{\scriptsize 26 Boulevard Dr Petitjean, \\ Dijon}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Tuteur de stage:} \\
Dr. Murphy \textsc{Wan} \\% Supervisor's Name\\
{\small University of Food Sciences}\\
{\scriptsize 6NO1,\,Kadoorie Biological Science Building,\\Hong Kong}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large Stage r\'ealis\'e du 23 Mars au 7 Ao\^ut 2015}\\[0.5cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise
{\large Ann\'e\'e 2015}\\[1cm]
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}
\newpage

\definecolor{tableheading}{rgb}{0.82,0.82,0.82} 
\definecolor{tableheadingg}{rgb}{0.90,0.90,0.90} 
\definecolor{softblue}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,1} %Change the bar color 
\arrayrulecolor{black}


 \title{Oat\,\textgreek{b} -glucan\,in\,ApoE\,-/- mice: focus\,on\,the\,gut\,integrity\,and\,endotoxemia.}
 \author{Anais Zouaki
\footnote{Corresponding author. Email: jane.doe@mailprovider.com.}, 
\textit{University of Hong Kong}.\\}
 \date{August, 7th. 2015}

 \maketitle
 \HRule \\[0.4cm]

\begin{abstract}
According to the \ac{efsa}, the $\beta$-glucan found in oat maintain a normal blood \ac{ldl} cholesterol concentration, increase the satiety leading to a reduction of energy intake, reduction of post-prandial glycemic responses and digestive function, but the relation between oat activity and  \ac{mw} remain unclear.  This study aim to evaluate the effects of oat $\beta$-glucan on gut health with different oat preparations \ac{mw} . A special focus was done on tight junction arrangement, endotoxemia level and gut microbiota. The quantification of intestine mRNA tight junctions reveal a difference between the role played by \ac{lmw} $\beta$-glucan compared to \ac{hmw} $\beta$-glucan and oat unrefined. Tree endotoxins where look at in this study, \ac{lps}, D-lactate and \ac{fmo}. The endotoxins data in this study stay unclear to understand the benefits or cons effects of oat on endotoxemia. The \ac{lps} seems to decrease in contrary to the D-lactate and \ac{fmo} which are higher with oat diets compared to western diet (one of the control group). Finally the key point seem to be the gut microbiota modification induced by oat diets which play an active role on all of those parameters. The data of the gut microbiota population  are currently being running and will probably give us relevant informations to understand those phenomenons. 
\end{abstract}

 \HRule \\[1cm]
\\
\\

\textbf{Keywords}: \textit{Oat\,- \,\textgreek{b} -glucan \, – \,Gut\,health\,– \,Tights\,junctions\, –\, Endotoxemia .}
\newpage

 \maketitle
\begin{abstract}
resume en francais
\end{abstract}
\newpage


\tableofcontents
\newpage

{\small \listoffigures}

{\small \listoftables}
\newpage

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\newpage
```

[how my text look like after I tried to align my accronymes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTCmF.png)[image: here is how my abbreviation look like ( they appear like this on the first page not where i tried to put them]

Comment: Welcome, i get several errors with your code, but any text added to your code gives justified text. Can you try to boil down your code [using this linked simple method](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)?

Comment: @Johannes_B Good idea to include the hyperlink.

Comment: There is no `\acsetup` here – you don't seem to change the layout of the acronym list at all?! (Not the question here but please have a look at the `chemmacros` package for writing compound names. More importantly: don't use `\\ ` for inserting vertical space or at the end of a paragraph.)